# update ajax send() content

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to receive data from ajax call and then send this data back using ajax.
**javascript code:**
`setInterval (function ()
    {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var content = "data=1";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
              {
                content = "data=" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
        }
      xmlhttp.open("POST" , "execute-page.php" , true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send(content);
    },5000);`
the problem now is that it keeps sending the old content. how can I update content variable with ajax response text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line `var content = "data=1";` out of the function:

```
var content = "data=1";
setInterval (function ()
    {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
              {
                content = "data=" + xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
        }
      xmlhttp.open("POST" , "execute-page.php" , true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send(content);
    },5000);
```